Error Message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'projects'
I am working on a Django application where I am trying to webscrape data and then insert the data into the Django ORM to be able to render it using HTML.  However, when I try to connect to the models.py file in the projects folder in the webscrape.py file I get an error message:       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'projects'.
Here is my project structure:

app
projects
init.py
models.py
tests.py
views.py
urls.py
admin.py
Scripts
Webscrape.py
init.py`

Here is the code inside my webscrape.py file:
from projects.models import Weather

Here is the code inside my models.py file:
from django.db import models

class Weather(models.Model):
    Date = models.DateField(blank=False, default='1900-01-01',)
    Temperature = models.CharField(max_length=15)

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
    'projects.apps.ProjectsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'huey.contrib.djhuey',
    'Scripts',
]

I have tried to update the sys.path with no avail and keep getting an error message.  Any help is much appreciated!
Directory Structure

Show us your directory layout.

Apologies the formatting got all screwed up when I posted the question.
├── app
│   ├── projects
│          ├── init.py
│          ├── models.py
│          ├── views.py
│          ├── tests.py
│          ├── urls.py
│          └── admin.py
└── Scripts
├── init.py
├── Webscrape.py

I included a picture of the structure as an edit to my question under "Directory Structure"

INSTALLED_APPS has  projects.apps.ProjectsConfig, but there is no projects/apps.py file.  What is projects.apps supposed to be?

This the code that is supposed to be there.  I added and ran my script but still running  into the same ModuleNotFoundError.
from django.apps import AppConfig
class ProjectsConfig(AppConfig):
default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
name = 'projects'

I added and ran my script This is too vague.  What script did you add, and what script did you run?

I added the following code to the apps.py file under my projects module.
from django.apps import AppConfig
class ProjectsConfig(AppConfig):
default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
name = 'projects'
Then, I tried to rerun my webscrape.py code which is the following
from projects.models import Weather
Recieved the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'projects'

Then, I tried to rerun my webscrape.py code Oh, so you're running this as a plain script?  It's not deployed as a standard web app?

Show us the webscrape.py file.

I am new to Django so may be using the wrong terminology here.  It is going to be deployed as webapp but right now I am just trying to get the script to run on its own inside of the application to confirm it is working correctly.  Eventually, I plan to have the webscrape.py code run as a scheduled task to scrape the data, add the data to my apps ORM, and then display it on my webpage.

If you want to run part of the app as a standalone script, you have to follow these directions https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage

Thank you so much!  I updated my webscrape.py file based on the document you sent and its running without error now.
